# how to set responsive width for user control in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm working on a windows form application and I have a parent form I call the user controls through it, the problem is when the parent form is maximized the user control appears well
[image]

but when I minimize the parent form I see that a part of the user control becomes hidden.

[image]

although I show the user control inside the panel and I set the dock for this panel to Fill.

and I use the following code to show that user control inside the panel:

```
        xUc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.PnlView.Controls.Clear();
        this.PnlView.Controls.Add(xUc);
        xUc.BringToFront();
```

Updtae1:
I used the `TableLayoutPanel` in the user control and I faced the same problem:

Minimized Form:
[image]

Maxmized Form:
[image]

Comment: You may have set the UserControl Dock property to Fill, but that doesn't mean you setup the controls within the UserControl to react accordingly to a size change. You have three columns and three rows, did you by chance use a `TableLayoutPanel`? How are those controls placed in the UserControl and setup? You won't get a nice resizable grid like that using only Anchor/Dock properties.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I tried now The `TableLayoutPanel` but with the same problem I made the dock of the `TableLayoutPanel` to Fill, I updated the post to see what happened.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel dock should be set to fill, but more importantly you have setup the controls within the cells of the TableLayoutPanel to dock fill as well, and make the columns/rows evenly distribute their widths/heights in the setup.

Comment: @Idle_Mind actually, I did :(

Comment: Well, don't tell us what you did. SHOW us your settings for these various controls. Otherwise we'll probably never figure it out....

Comment: @dr.null your answer is right please add it as answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshots denote the two panels are not hosted by the same parent. You can verify that by checking what do you have in the `PnlView.Controls` collection or by  checking the `Parent` property of the left and right panels. So, `xUc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` does not give you the expected dock layout, it fills the *free space* of the `PnlView`.

To get the expected layout, make sure to host the two panels by the same parent, if that is not an option (for example, the right panel is some sort of *floating* panels) then handle the relevant events (i.e. `Parent.SizeChanged`, `RightPanel.VisibleChanged`...etc) to set the bounds (mainly the width) of the left panel.